# Is there any php CalDav client library?

Tags: php, calendar, caldav

I install my own CalDav Server using Chandler Cosmo or DAViCal Calendar Server. I wanna use php as a CalDAV Client. But I cannot see a php library like a caldav4j in java.

Does anyone have a recommended library or have some advice to do this in the other way ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php library or client for a caldav server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819468/php-library-or-client-for-a-caldav-server)

Answer (score 4):

DAViCal includes inc/caldav-client-v2.php which provides a library of useful PHP methods  to enable development of a client.  It also includes a basic script in scripts/sync-remote-caldav.php which can be used for (e.g.) synchronising a DAViCal calendar with a remote calendar via CalDAV.

Very recent versions of DAViCal also include code to allow an "external binding" where a calendar which appears to be in DAViCal is actually external.

Comment: Does it support Digest Authentication?

Comment: I don't think so.  Digest is fundamentally insecure and really should not be used other than in extremely tightly controlled environments, and really even not then.

Comment: @kaora and what do you reccomend, the basic access authentication ? :))

Answer (score 2):

Is [this](http://repo.or.cz/w/davical.git/blob/HEAD:/inc/caldav-client.php) what you're looking for?  It's a php class (`caldav-client.php`) from DAViCal that can connect to a CalDAV server.

Comment: It does not support Digest Authentication.