# php library or client for a caldav server

Tags: php, jquery, calendar, caldav

i've set up a caldav server in particular http://radicale.org/ and now i would to integrate a jquery calendar like http://themouette.github.com/jquery-week-calendar/weekcalendar.html but the problem is the interface in php.

so the question is:
there is a library written in php to interact with radicale server or just another caldav server? How is possible to create, modify and delete events?

I do not know how the protocol works, but I thought that you could use curl.

Best regards
Claudio

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a decent SabreDAV Wrapper, you should try http://baikal.codr.fr
It's lightweight, full PHP, and features a nice web admin for managing contacts and calendars.

Comment: It is not really ideal since it is dead and one has to wonder about the status of the project, but for those who really want to access it, you can find it on the "Way Back Machine" [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20121116071008/http://baikal.codr.fr/).

Comment: To add to my previous comment, there is an active github account [here](https://github.com/jeromeschneider/Baikal)

Answer (score 1):

I use [SabreDAV](http://sabre.io/), a PHP framework for Web/Cal/CardDAV. It defines backends you have to implement in order to create your own server. It's full featured and probably the best lib In PHP.

It works fine and I also use the same calendar ;)

Comment: Yes, I had a look at it and played with it too, but the learning curve is steep. It would be nice to have an extra layer to simplify rather than to have to read the rfc and the intricacies of CalDav protocol