# How to search CalDav Blob from MySql Db?

Tags: php, mysql, blob, caldav

I'm currently trying to integrate a CalDav Calendar into my website. 
I'm using "baikal" and it actually works fine, i'm already able to access my 
calendar via iphone, macbook and so on.

What I wanna do now is reading the Events from the mysql database and display 
them in my own calendar. 
It works fine so far, I found a library that can parse these Blobs which stores all calendardata.

My problem now is:
How can I search through this blob? For example, i want to display all events between date x and y, or display all events that contain "concert" in the summary/title.

I did some research on this but i wasn't able to find anything so I thought I ask!

looking forward to your replies and thanks in advance!
david

Comment: Have you considered storing the data in MySQL (a *relational database management system*) in a *relational* form and then parsing from /  serialising into CalDav format on insertion / retrieval ?

Comment: they are already stored in my mysql database, but there is one column "calendardata" which is a blob and stores the whole calendardata..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use CalDAV to access the calendar, instead of trying to directly hit the MySQL DB ? From what I understand, you don't even own the schema as it comes from the Baikal server (?...) so you are running the risk of having to redo the work if/when Baikal changes the way they store the data.

Another advantage is that you are guaranteed to get a more consistent result: for example, time range queries (from date x to date y) can be tricky so by using CalDAV queries, both CalDAV clients and your calendar are going to return the same set of events whereas by trying to implement something on your own, you will likely diverge from what the CalDAV server returns.

There are php CalDAV clients. See for example [Is there any php CalDav client library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235651/is-there-any-php-caldav-client-library)

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791#section-7.8.1 for a timerange based CalDAV query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your message!
Ok, so I do store the caldav database on my own server and I also added some columns here and there to store the rest of my data.

I don't know if it's Baikal itself who defines the format the events are stored in? Does anybody know that?

Thank you also for the links you posted, I will try that DAViCal library and see if it works with the baikal..

Thanks again!
Further help/ideads is absolutely welcome :)

Comment: Hi again, I tried to use the inc_caldav-client-v2.php but i can't get it to work.. I always get an error:
Sabre\DAV\Exception\NotAuthenticated
  No digest authentication headers were found
  1.8.6

any help is welcome...

Comment: the caldav client seems to support only HTTP Basic authentication so you would have to check whether the Sabre server can be configured to accept basic authentication.

Comment: You're the man! That was it..!! now need to find out how to do some filtering :)

Comment: One more question! Is it possible somehow to search through all events? Without the need to authenticate? For example I want a list that displays all events from all users on June, 14th 2014 or so.. What would be the best way?

Comment: Can't do that with CalDAV unless the server you are talking to has a special hook to do so.

Comment: Oh that sucks... :( Do you have some links to that topic?