# Get Yahoo calendars

Tags: php, curl, calendar, yahoo

I'm trying to get list of Yahoo calendars using the next code.

```
$url = "https://calendar.yahoo.com/";
$user = "****@yahoo.com";
$pwd = "*****";
$body = "<A:propfind xmlns:A='DAV:'>
                            <A:prop>
                                <A:displayname/>
                            </A:prop>
                        </A:propfind>";
$c=curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Depth: 1", "Content-Type: text/xml; charset='UTF-8'", "User-Agent: DAVKit/4.0.1 (730); CalendarStore/4.0.1 (973); iCal/4.0.1 (1374); Mac OS X/10.6.2 (10C540)"));
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user.":".$pwd);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PROPFIND");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data=curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
```

But in response i've got 500 Error. 
Any idea?

Also I'm trying use this link https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com, but it's too 500 Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my case

```
       $xml = "<A:propfind xmlns:A='DAV:'>
                            <A:prop>
                                <A:displayname/>
                            </A:prop>
                        </A:propfind>";

        $url = sprintf("https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/dav/%s/Calendar", $email);

        $headers = array(
            'Depth: 1',
            'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Length: '.strlen($xml),
            "User-Agent: DAVKit/4.0.1 (730); CalendarStore/4.0.1 (973); iCal/4.0.1 (1374); Mac OS X/10.6.2 (10C540)"
        );

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $email.":".$password);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PROPFIND');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, if you look at the source code of that page, you've got allllll of these hidden `input` fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="sessionId" id="sessionId" value="8nPh4sVBtxEZ">
<input type="hidden" name=".tries" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name=".src" value="yc">
<input type="hidden" name=".md5" value="">
<input type="hidden" name=".hash" value="">
<input type="hidden" name=".js" value="">
<input type="hidden" name=".last" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="promo" value="">
<input type="hidden" name=".intl" value="us">
<input type="hidden" name=".lang" value="en-US">
<input type="hidden" name=".bypass" value="">
<input type="hidden" name=".partner" value="">
<input type="hidden" name=".u" value="336ng15a3fsqq">
<input type="hidden" name=".v" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name=".challenge" value="vrO9R3b_b7Qwm8roug2Ea0jjlIh022jt4w--">
<input type="hidden" name=".yplus" value="">
<input type="hidden" name=".emailCode" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="pkg" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="stepid" value="">
<input type="hidden" name=".ev" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="hasMsgr" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name=".chkP" value="Y">
<input type="hidden" name=".done" value="http://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/">
<input type="hidden" name=".pd" value="yc_ver=0&c=&ivt=&sg=">
<input type="hidden" name=".ws" id=".ws" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name=".cp" id=".cp" value="0">     
<input type="hidden" name="nr" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="pad" id="pad" value="6">
<input type="hidden" name="aad" id="aad" value="6">
```

And in one of those, you'll notice

```
<input type="hidden" name=".challenge" value="vrO9R3b_b7Qwm8roug2Ea0jjlIh022jt4w--">
```

That is what is causing the "500 Error." Why? Because you're writing a bot/scraper and the login form uses [CSRF protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) among other hack prevention techniques. Yahoo and all the big guys are actively writing code to stop you from doing exactly that.

If you're truly trying to interface with the CalDAV protocol that Yahoo provides, you'll probably need to be using a much different approach than cURL requests. There's probably [some discussion of CalDAV PHP Client libraries out there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5235651/1188035)

Comment: I'm trying to do this with DAViCal
This is my sorce 

`require_once('davical/inc/caldav-client.php');

$cal = new CalDAVClient(
    "https://caldav.calendar.yahoo.com/",
    "*****@yahoo.com",
    "******"
);
$options = $cal->DoOptionsRequest();
var_dump($options);`

But on response I get 502 error.